# How to get a widget position inside it's layout in Kivy?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I have a GridLayout and I added some Image widgets on it after adding of images I want to draw a rectangle in each image by using their canvas but I couldn't because I don't know the exact Image widgets positions on GridLayout.

In last line of my Python code : `Rectangle(pos = (child.x - 2.4, child.y + 467), size = (70, 70))`

How to draw this rectangle in child(My method is not good^),

Also Why my GridLayout not coming in center after setting it's `pos_hint = {"center_x" : .5}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand question right, try to use such methods as [`to_local()`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.to_local), [`to_parent()`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.to_parent), [`to_widget()`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.to_widget) and [`to_window()`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.to_window). Also you could try to subtract position of your GridLayout from Widgets' positions.

Comment: @user3667673, what about substracting?

Comment: I don't have Widgets positions "self.pos" is (0,0)!

Comment: @user3667673, by the way, what about [`canvas.after`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.instructions.html?highlight=canvas.after#kivy.graphics.instructions.Canvas.after)?

Comment: I'am using canvas.after because I want to hide images also results for all of the above methods are same for my layout.pos and widgets.pos!

Comment: @user3667673, can you post some code in your question?

Comment: @afhacker, it seems you need FloatLayout instead of BoxLayout/GridLayout. Or maybe just Layout.